# How can I access embedded ASP.NET GlobalResources in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm working on a legacy ASP.NET project, which I'm trying to massage into shape slowly, but I can't make significant changes without it all collapsing like a chocolate finger house....

I've tried to find a solution for this, but failed miserably due to the specific mix of terminology ("javascript", "embedded" and/or "resource" just give me information as to how to embed a .js file...), and the fact that it's probably a weird way of doing things.

The project makes use of App_GlobalResources for translatable strings, which is used in C# code behind, the markup and in some of the JavaScript. For example:

HTML:

```
Text="<%$Resources: Resources, MeasuresLabel %>"
```

JS:

```
setDialogTitle('summaryDialog', physicalElementName, Resources.Resources.Summary);
```

This was all working fine, until we started using NUnit for some integration testing. To make the Resources.resx available to NUnit I've followed Scott Allen's [suggestion](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx), which works for NUnit but means that the above *Resources.Resources* is undefined.

So, my question is with this embedded file, how can I make it accessible to the JavaScript (or is there a better way I can make it available to NUnit)?

There's an the added complication due to the code I want to access it with being in separate .js files, rather than within script tags in the .aspx files.

**EDIT**
After looking at it some more, the real challenge is the properties that are accessed in the JS are static. Due to the number of places these are referenced, it's not practical to add a variable for each string that's being used.

Answer (score 0):

I think that JS files aren't going through the ASP.NET engine and they are served as they are, that's why Resources.Resources.Summary isn't defined in your case, while it will work when embedded inside `<script>` tag in .aspx file.
The only way I know around this would be to store the used resource values in global javascript variables on the .aspx page and then use them in loaded JS files.

Comment: Would the syntax be something like this?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        var Resources = '<%=Res %>';
    </script>

Comment: Yes, but be sure to escape the ' in Res string, so you don't end up with var Resources = 'This isn't good';.